# Density of Differential Operators

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

Let $X$ be a smooth variety over a field $k$ of characteristic zero.  Let $E,F$ be vector bundles on $X$, and write their associated sheaves of sections as $\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F}$.  Define the set of differential operators from $E$ to $F$, written $D(E,F)$, as those $T\in Hom_{\underline{k}}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F})$ such that for every affine open $Spec(A)\subseteq X$ there exists some $n$ such that $[[\cdots[T,a_1],\cdots],a_n]=0$ for all $n$-tuples $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in A^{n}$.

Now, if $M\subseteq\Gamma(X,E)$ is a finite-dimensional subspace, there is a natural map $D(E,F)\to Hom_k(M,\Gamma(X,F))$ given by restricting differential operators to $M$ as linear maps.

If $X$ is affine, one can show that this restriction map is surjective for *any* such $M$.  My question is whether or not this map is surjective for any $X$, i.e. not necessarily affine.

What I know we can say is that we have a surjective map of sheaves $D(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F})\to Hom_{\underline{k}}(\underline{M},\mathcal{F})$ where $D(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F})$ is the sheaf whose values on an open set $U$ are differential operators from $E|_U$ to $F|_U$ (follows from the statement on affines).  But of course the global sections of this map is not necessarily surjective, which is the map of interest, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's false.

If it is false, what conditions can we impose to guarantee density?

Comment: I think it is false. For instance, let us say $X$ is a curve of genus at least two, and $E=F$ is a line bundle. Then the only globally defined differential operators $E\to E$ are constants (this can be easily seen because the leading term of a differential operator is a section of $T_X^{\otimes d}$, which automatically vanishes if $d>0$ because of the genus condition). However, if $E$ is very positive, there are many non-constant maps $\Gamma(X,E)\to\Gamma(X,E)$.